# While loop inside multiple if condition in android studio

Tags: java, android, if-statement, while-loop

I'm using while loop and inside am using two if statements.

```
while(cr.moveToNext()){
    if(cr.getCount() > 0){
        if((cr.getString(5).equals(username)) && cr.getString(6).equals(password)
          && cr.getString(14).equals("success")) {
            String un = cr.getString(2);
            String uc = cr.getString(1);
            String rc = cr.getString(4);
            ......................
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In this scenario, if I passed wrong value "Invalid Login" is executing many times [as it is inside while loop] and If I pass correct values both successfully login and  Invalid login message is showing. How to make if condition to be properly work in this type of scenario...

Comment: what is your expected result?  do you want to exit the loop on first failure or success? if so just remove your while loop. you can call cr.moveToFirst () if you need to iterate back to the start of the cursor again.

Comment: @AngelKoh..If I remove while loop it checks only for the first data and for the remaining datas it shows invalid login... I need to check the conditions for all datas..

Comment: so you want to  verify that ALL the data is valid before starting Activities for ALL of them, and if any one fails, do not start any activity at all? if so, then you just need to iterate the cursor twice (the first to check that all is in order, the second to start the activities).

Comment: @AngelKoh yes right I need to verify all the datas..can you plz show me the syntax...

Comment: do take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to check that everything is in order before starting the activities you can do the loop twice, like below.

I also used do while, so as not to skip the first result.

```
private void handleCursor(Cursor cr){
    boolean everythingGood = true;
    do{
        
        if (cr.getCount() > 14) { // <- if you are using cr.getString(14) 
                                  //to get "Success" string, then you should 
                                  //check for that too
            if (!checkSuccess(cr)  )   
                everythingGood = false;                 }
        }else {
            //not enough columns received.. assumed login fail.
            //do your failure workflow
            everythingGood = false;
        }
    } while(cr.moveToNext() && everythingGood);

    if(everythingGood){
        //second loop (no need to check any more, just spawn the activities)
       cr.moveToFirst();
        do{
           createActivities(cr); 
        }while(cr.moveToNext();
    }else {
        handleFailure();
    }
}
```

I moved your check condition out to another function to make it easier to see the while loop

```
private boolean checkSuccess(Cursor cr){
 return cr.getString(5).equals(username)) && cr.getString(6).equals(password)
            && cr.getString(14).equals("success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use break; or you can use a boolean flag variable , at first keep it true, then enter the conditions if it is true and once entered make the flag variable false in side that condition.

```
 Boolean isValid;
    isValid = true;
    while(cr.moveToNext())
    { 
        if (cr.getCount() > 0)
        { 
            if ((cr.getString(5).equals(username))
            && cr.getString(6).equals(password) && cr.getString(14).equals("success"))
                { 
                    if (isValid) 
                    {
                        isValid=false;
                        String un = cr.getString(2);
                    }
                }
            else { .......... } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used boolean flag variable but it is not working... `
Boolean isValid;
isValid = true;


while(cr.moveToNext()) {
                if (cr.getCount() > 0) {
                    if (isValid) {
                        if ((cr.getString(5).equals(username)) && cr.getString(6).equals(password)
                                && cr.getString(14).equals("success")) {
                            String un = cr.getString(2);
       ...........
       } else {
       ..........
      }
     }
`

Is my syntax right...

Comment: you also need to make the boolean variable false once it enters the main if condition. or make it something like this: code given in answer

Comment: In your code I need to pass isValid = false or isValid = true...to get all the datas from the query..